# JS cursor is fixed to top/left of viewport until mouse is moved

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-cursor

**Position on Page Load**

I have a custom JS cursor that's working well but I've noticed when the page loads the 2 (styled) divs that form the cursor are fixed in the top/left of the viewport until the mouse is moved - then the divs attach to the pointer and work as expected.

Is it possible to get the cursor the appear in the correct position - where the pointer is on the screen - immediately on load?

If that's not possible, could an alternative be to add a class to the body when the mouse is moved and then I fade in the cursor?

**Mobile**

On mobile I've hidden the cursor with the CSS below - but would it be better to stop the JS running as well and if so how could I do that?

```
@media (hover: none) {
        
    .cursor,
    .cursor-outer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**Default Browser Cursor**

I hide the browser cursor with the CSS below but I've noticed every now and then the cursor appears above my custom cursor. Not sure if this is down to me leaving it idle in tabs or resizing?

```
* {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```js
var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor-outer');
var cursorinner = document.querySelector('.cursor');
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a');
 
var moveCursor = true;
var radiusOfCursor = parseInt(getComputedStyle(cursor).getPropertyValue('width')) / 2; // radiusOfCursor = (width_of_cursor / 2).
     
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  cursorinner.style.left = x + 'px';
  cursorinner.style.top = y + 'px';
  
  if (!moveCursor) return;
  
  cursor.style.marginLeft = `calc(${e.clientX}px - ${radiusOfCursor}px)`;
  cursor.style.marginTop = `calc(${e.clientY}px - ${radiusOfCursor}px)`; 
  
  moveCursor = false;
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    moveCursor = true;
  }, 32) // The wait time. I chose 95 because it seems to work just fine for me.
});
 
 /* Centre pointer after stopping */
 
function mouseMoveEnd() {
  cursor.style.marginLeft = `calc(${cursorinner.style.left} - ${radiusOfCursor}px)`;
  cursor.style.marginTop = `calc(${cursorinner.style.top} - ${radiusOfCursor}px)`;
}
 
var x;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() { 
  if (x) clearTimeout(x); 
  x = setTimeout(mouseMoveEnd, 10); 
}, false);
 
 /* End */
 
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  cursor.classList.add('click');
  cursorinner.classList.add('cursorinnerhover');
});
 
 document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  cursor.classList.remove('click');
  cursorinner.classList.remove('cursorinnerhover');
 });
 
a.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    cursor.classList.add('hover');
  });
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    cursor.classList.remove('hover');
  });
});
 
a.forEach((item) => {
  const interaction = item.dataset.interaction;
  
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    cursorinner.classList.add(interaction);
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    cursorinner.classList.remove(interaction);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

.cursor-outer {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: height .12s ease-out, margin .12s ease-out, opacity .12s ease-out, width .12s ease-out;
    width: 32px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.cursor {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: height .12s, opacity .12s, width .12s;
    width: 4px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.hover {
    height: 4px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 4px;
}

.cursorinnerhover {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;   
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor-outer"></div>
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: By "correct position immediately on load", do you mean in center ?

Comment: *"to get the cursor the appear in the correct position"* what do you think is a *"correct position"* exactly? You could allow the camera, enable an eye tracker, and place the cursor  where the user is looking at. Would that make it correct-er?

Comment: If you ask me, I would not show the cursor at all — until a first (mousemove) interaction is triggered.

Comment: Never move elements on a page using `margin`.

Comment: Just where the mouse is already the screen @ShravanDhar and Roko :) So sounds like hiding and adding a class when moved would be preferable? Also sound like JS could be updated to use top/left instead of margin then?

Comment: How can I add a class to the body once the user has moved the mouse. Then I will hide default cursor and display custom one